# How to hide text in post titles?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I need help figuring out how to hide text in post titles, but make them visible for search engines.

For example, in the post title, the text is "**[Movie News] Spiderman may appear in the Venom movie**", but the visible text for that post title inside the post is "**Spiderman may appear in the Venom movie**".

But when people find it on Google, the text would be the original post title, aka, "**[Movie News] Spiderman may appear in the Venom movie**".

I've seen few websites do that but never actually figured out how to do it on my own. Thanks in advance to whoever can help me out with this.

Comment: Google and other search engines WILL find them, but ignore and/or give you a penalty, because you trying to cheat. I highly advise against it!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Maybe stick the [Movie News] (etc) part in the page `<title>` and the part without the prefix in your `<h1>` (or whatever you're using for the heading)? That way you're not tricking anyone, can make it nice and readable for users and semantically meaningful for search. Although really it feels like more of a question for [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Easy as hello : don't give them any height, and hide the overflow.

```css
.article {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 12px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.search-engine {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}

.title {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <div class="search-engine">[Movie News] Spiderman may appear in the Venom movie</div>
  <div class="title">Spiderman may appear in the Venom movie</div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

If you can type in some JS, add this

```
const titles = document.getElementsByClassName('your class that is applied to your titles')
for (const title of titles) {
  const SEstring = title.textContent;
  title.textContent = title.textContent.replace(/^\s*\[[\w\s]*]\s*/, '');
  const SEelement = document.createElement('div');
  SEelement.style.height = '0';
  SEelement.style.maxHeight = '0';
  SEelement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  SEelement.textContent = SEstring;
  document.insertBefore(SEelement, title);
}
```

This will remove the text and the brackets from your title, and create a non-visible div just before it with the title and the brackets. The same thing done in the snippet, but in JS !

Comment: How do I implement it in the Blogger?

Comment: Oh so your tag isn't actually your work title :O Sorry, I don't know, I make all of my code by hand ...

Comment: Yeah, the text I want to hide is inside my every post title... Oh well, thanks for your help anyhow.

Comment: I can still give you some help if you can type in some javascript ?

Comment: go ahead, would be nice.